# Google OR-TOOLS VRP Problem with previous OR-TOOLS Assignment problem

Tags: python, or-tools

Im trying to solve a 2 step problem, where in the first one I run an assignment model which calculates the best option that optimize the pick up and deliveries arcs between nodes because not all the vehicles can transport the same products and other complications the problem has. The result of the first model are the arcs that serves as an input in the second VRP model as data['pickups_deliveries'].  The next code is an easy example where the code works but a node cant be a delivery and also a pickup node at the same time. Which is what i need to solve.

```
"""Capacited Vehicles Routing Problem (CVRP)."""

from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp


def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = [
        [
            0, 548, 776, 696, 582, 274, 502, 194, 308, 194, 536, 502, 388, 354,
            468, 776, 662
        ],
        [
            548, 0, 684, 308, 194, 502, 730, 354, 696, 742, 1084, 594, 480, 674,
            1016, 868, 1210
        ],
        [
            776, 684, 0, 992, 878, 502, 274, 810, 468, 742, 400, 1278, 1164,
            1130, 788, 1552, 754
        ],
        [
            696, 308, 992, 0, 114, 650, 878, 502, 844, 890, 1232, 514, 628, 822,
            1164, 560, 1358
        ],
        [
            582, 194, 878, 114, 0, 536, 764, 388, 730, 776, 1118, 400, 514, 708,
            1050, 674, 1244
        ],
        [
            274, 502, 502, 650, 536, 0, 228, 308, 194, 240, 582, 776, 662, 628,
            514, 1050, 708
        ],
        [
            502, 730, 274, 878, 764, 228, 0, 536, 194, 468, 354, 1004, 890, 856,
            514, 1278, 480
        ],
        [
            194, 354, 810, 502, 388, 308, 536, 0, 342, 388, 730, 468, 354, 320,
            662, 742, 856
        ],
        [
            308, 696, 468, 844, 730, 194, 194, 342, 0, 274, 388, 810, 696, 662,
            320, 1084, 514
        ],
        [
            194, 742, 742, 890, 776, 240, 468, 388, 274, 0, 342, 536, 422, 388,
            274, 810, 468
        ],
        [
            536, 1084, 400, 1232, 1118, 582, 354, 730, 388, 342, 0, 878, 764,
            730, 388, 1152, 354
        ],
        [
            502, 594, 1278, 514, 400, 776, 1004, 468, 810, 536, 878, 0, 114,
            308, 650, 274, 844
        ],
        [
            388, 480, 1164, 628, 514, 662, 890, 354, 696, 422, 764, 114, 0, 194,
            536, 388, 730
        ],
        [
            354, 674, 1130, 822, 708, 628, 856, 320, 662, 388, 730, 308, 194, 0,
            342, 422, 536
        ],
        [
            468, 1016, 788, 1164, 1050, 514, 514, 662, 320, 274, 388, 650, 536,
            342, 0, 764, 194
        ],
        [
            776, 868, 1552, 560, 674, 1050, 1278, 742, 1084, 810, 1152, 274,
            388, 422, 764, 0, 798
        ],
        [
            662, 1210, 754, 1358, 1244, 708, 480, 856, 514, 468, 354, 844, 730,
            536, 194, 798, 0
        ],
    ]
    data['pickups_deliveries'] = [
        [1, 6],
        [2, 10],
        [4, 3],
        [5, 9],
        [7, 8],
        [15, 11],
        [13, 12],
        [16, 14]
    ]
    data['demands'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    data['vehicle_capacities'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 9
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    print(f'Objective: {solution.ObjectiveValue()}')
    total_distance = 0
    total_load = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        route_load = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            node_index = manager.IndexToNode(index)
            route_load += data['demands'][node_index]
            plan_output += ' {0} Load({1}) -> '.format(node_index, route_load)
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += ' {0} Load({1})\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index),
                                                 route_load)
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        plan_output += 'Load of the route: {}\n'.format(route_load)
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
        total_load += route_load
    print('Total distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))
    print('Total load of all routes: {}'.format(total_load))


def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    # [START data]
    data = create_data_model()
    # [END data]

    # Create the routing index manager.
    # [START index_manager]
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    # [END index_manager]

    # Create Routing Model.
    # [START routing_model]
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

    # [END routing_model]

    # Define cost of each arc.
    # [START arc_cost]
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)
    # [END arc_cost]

    # Add Distance constraint.
    # [START distance_constraint]
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)
    # [END distance_constraint]

    # Define Transportation Requests.
    # [START pickup_delivery_constraint]
    for request in data['pickups_deliveries']:
        pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
        delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
        routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
        routing.solver().Add(
            routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
                delivery_index))
        routing.solver().Add(
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))
    routing.SetPickupAndDeliveryPolicyOfAllVehicles(
        pywrapcp.RoutingModel.PICKUP_AND_DELIVERY_FIFO)
    # [END pickup_delivery_constraint]

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PATH_CHEAPEST_ARC)
    search_parameters.local_search_metaheuristic = (
        routing_enums_pb2.LocalSearchMetaheuristic.GUIDED_LOCAL_SEARCH)
    search_parameters.time_limit.FromSeconds(1)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
Route for vehicle 0:
 0 Load(1) ->  4 Load(2) ->  3 Load(3) ->  5 Load(4) ->  9 Load(5) ->  0 Load(5)
Distance of the route: 1780m
Load of the route: 5

Route for vehicle 1:
 0 Load(1) ->  2 Load(2) ->  10 Load(3) ->  0 Load(3)
Distance of the route: 1712m
Load of the route: 3

Route for vehicle 2:
 0 Load(1) ->  0 Load(1)
Distance of the route: 0m
Load of the route: 1

Route for vehicle 3:
 0 Load(1) ->  0 Load(1)
Distance of the route: 0m
Load of the route: 1

Route for vehicle 4:
 0 Load(1) ->  0 Load(1)
Distance of the route: 0m
Load of the route: 1

Route for vehicle 5:
 0 Load(1) ->  0 Load(1)
Distance of the route: 0m
Load of the route: 1

Route for vehicle 6:
 0 Load(1) ->  1 Load(2) ->  6 Load(3) ->  0 Load(3)
Distance of the route: 1780m
Load of the route: 3

Route for vehicle 7:
 0 Load(1) ->  7 Load(2) ->  8 Load(3) ->  16 Load(4) ->  14 Load(5) ->  0 Load(5)
Distance of the route: 1712m
Load of the route: 5

Route for vehicle 8:
 0 Load(1) ->  13 Load(2) ->  12 Load(3) ->  15 Load(4) ->  11 Load(5) ->  0 Load(5)
Distance of the route: 1712m
Load of the route: 5
```

This code works fine for simple graph assignment where **each pickup node is just a pickup node and each delivery node is just a delivery node**. But if a want a node to be pickup and delivery, I thought i can add this as another graph, for example, making node 14, former delivery node, also  a pickup node for the arc[14,13]. I thought i could force one vehicle to go 16->14->13->12 by adding this to the data['pickups_deliveries'] but python collapse and stops working.

```
data['pickups_deliveries'] = [
        [1, 6],
        [2, 10],
        [4, 3],
        [5, 9],
        [7, 8],
        [15, 11],
        [13, 12],
        [16, 14],
       [14,13] ## Added
    ]
```

**Mainly what I want to do is be able to add graphs where in one a node can be a pickup node and in another the same node can be a delivery one.**
Thanks and sorry for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

You must duplicate the node and adapt your transit callback accordingly.

Then you could merge node id when post processing the solution assignment.

Another way is to hack the transit callback to do the mapping there so you have to recompute a new transit matrix.
e.g.
create a duplicate node 17 and 18 for node 13 and 14.
so you can add the new P&D pair `[18, 17]`

in your transit callback:

```py
def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        # rebind 17 or 18 to 13 or 14 respectively
        if from_node in [17, 18]:
            from_node = from_node - 4
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        # rebind 17 or 18 to 13 or 14 respectively
        if to_node in [17, 18]:
            to_node = to_node - 4
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]
```

and also change

```py
    # [START index_manager]
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']) + 2,
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])
    # [END index_manager]
```

Comment: Thank you!! It really help. The problem that i have now is that one vehicle goes 16->14->13 and another that goes 13->12, and i was wondering if it is possible to force the complete route dependency 16->14->13->12 for one vehicle.  In the business case i need to make a pickup on the delivery points 14 and 13 and that pick up can only be deliver to node 13, and 12 that have to be de immediate next nodes .  I thought i could solve this by adding the vehicle capacity constrain=1  it but it didnt work. Thank you again